# Ruby and Rails Github Action exit code 16

Tags: ruby-on-rails, continuous-integration, github-actions

I am trying to set up a continuous integration workflow with Github actions for a new Rails project. This is the error:

```
2022-05-21T17:07:01.1242737Z Your bundle only supports platforms ["x86_64-darwin-19", "x86_64-darwin-21"] but
2022-05-21T17:07:01.1243516Z your local platform is x86_64-linux. Add the current platform to the lockfile
2022-05-21T17:07:01.1244782Z with `bundle lock --add-platform x86_64-linux` and try again.
2022-05-21T17:07:01.1294935Z Took   1.38 seconds
2022-05-21T17:07:01.1295823Z ##[endgroup]
2022-05-21T17:07:01.1347744Z ##[error]Error: The process '/opt/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.1.2/x64/bin/bundle' failed with exit code 16
    at ExecState._setResult (/home/runner/work/_actions/ruby/setup-ruby/v1/dist/index.js:4918:25)
    at ExecState.CheckComplete (/home/runner/work/_actions/ruby/setup-ruby/v1/dist/index.js:4901:18)
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/runner/work/_actions/ruby/setup-ruby/v1/dist/index.js:4795:27)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1064:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:301:5)
```

And the configuration file:

```
name: My workflow
on: [push, pull_request]
jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - uses: ruby/setup-ruby@v1
      with:
        bundler-cache: true
    - run: bundle exec rake
```

Does anybody know what the issue is?

Comment: Gerard, please select an answer.

Answer (score 36):

[ISSUE FIXED]

Solution:

Run `bundle lock --add-platform x86_64-linux`

Answer (score 11):

TL;DR

Run this command **locally** in your project and commit the changes

```
bundle lock --add-platform x86_64-linux
```

---

**Why does this work?**

The answers from **Gerard Morera** and **Wael Mohammed** are correct. Here's more detail to it:

Considering the following Github Actions config for Ruby:

```
...
  unit-test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - uses: ruby/setup-ruby@v1
      with:
        ruby-version: '3.0'
        bundler-cache: true
...
```

The config declares `ubuntu-latest` platform image for running the job on Github Actions.
Github Actions uses `x86_64-linux` platform for ubuntu. However, the `Gemfile.lock` is missing that platform leading to exit code 16.

Running the following command locally will add `x86_64-linux` platform to `Gemfile.lock`:

```
bundle lock --add-platform x86_64-linux
```

After running the command, the final `Gemfile.lock` looks similar to this:

```
...
PLATFORMS
  universal-darwin-22
  x64-mingw32
  x86_64-linux

DEPENDENCIES
  fastlane
...
```

The `x86_64-linux` is now added under `PLATFORMS` list in `Gemfile.lock`, therefore it will run correctly on ubuntu images of Github Actions.

Answer (score 8):

The answer provided by **Gerard Morera** worked fine for me; however, it took me a while to realise that I needed to run `bundle lock --add-platform x86_64-linux` via PowerShell/command line from within the project (it was a Jekyll project/site on my case).

It may also be helpful to highlight that the reason this issue appeared in my case was that I was bundling the site on Windows 10 while a Linux-powered machine handled the deployment (triggered/controlled by a GitHub workflow.