# bundle failed whit exit code 16, jekyll-theme-chirpy build error

Tags: ruby, server, jekyll, bundle

I want to apply this theme, but there is an error while building it.
It works in local, but it doesn't build.
https://github.com/rubygems/bundler/issues/4375
I saw it through this link, but I don't know how to match it because the server also says that using a fixed version of the bundler is the solution.

```
Error: The process '/opt/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.1.2/x64/bin/bundle' failed with exit code 16
    at ExecState._setResult (/home/runner/work/_actions/ruby/setup-ruby/v1/dist/index.js:6023:25)
    at ExecState.CheckComplete (/home/runner/work/_actions/ruby/setup-ruby/v1/dist/index.js:6006:18)
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/runner/work/_actions/ruby/setup-ruby/v1/dist/index.js:5900:27)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1064:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:301:5)
```

```
$ which jekyll
>>> /Users/GyeongminKim/.rbenv/shims/jekyll
$ which gem
>>> /Users/GyeongminKim/.rubies/ruby-3.1.2/bin/gem
$ which bundle
>>> /Users/GyeongminKim/.rubies/ruby-3.1.2/bin/bundle
$ bundle version
>>> Bundler version 2.3.7 (2022-09-15 commit unknown)
$ ruby --version
>>> ruby 3.1.2p20 (2022-04-12 revision 4491bb740a) [arm64-darwin21]
```

Comment: You can fix your bundler version, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57170296/bundler-could-not-find-compatible-versions-for-gem-bundler-in-gemfile/57172655#57172655 - regarding your question, I think I need further information. Can you share your _config.yml or Jekyll content ?

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error. This command helped me to resolve my issue:

```
bundle lock --add-platform x86_64-linux
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72331753/ruby-and-rails-github-action-exit-code-16)